# OK Button not returning to Activity after using Implcit Intent for Camera

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, android-implicit-intent

this question has been asked on this platform but none of them helped me.
So this application has a button **Click Photo** with a callback to *onPhotoClicked()*.
I have mentioned the **WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** permission in the Manifest.
After clicking the photo the cancel button returns to the activity but the ok button does nothing.

Here is the Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button emailButton, clickPhotoButton;
private static final String FILE_NAME="image01.jpg";
private static final int CAMERA_PIC_REUEST = 100;
private static final int REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
File pictureDir;
Uri fileUri;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    emailButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.email_button);
    clickPhotoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.click_photo_button);

    pictureDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "Prakhar");
    if(!pictureDir.exists()) {
        pictureDir.mkdirs();
    }

}

public void onPhotoClicked(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File image = new File(pictureDir, FILE_NAME);
    fileUri = Uri.fromFile(image);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_PIC_REUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if(requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        File image = new File(pictureDir, FILE_NAME);
        fileUri = Uri.fromFile(image);
        imageView.setImageURI(fileUri);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Any Log........?

Comment: @siva35 No. On cancelling however new messages appear. but on Ok button there is no changes in the log.